# Extract field from mongodb query result set

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

How to extract json field from query response in node js?

I have a query:-

```
const Allposts = await Post.aggregate([pipeline])
```

Allposts:-

```
  {
    _id: 1,
    type: 'A',
    source: 'B',
    status: 'C',
    totalCount: 7,
    createdAt: 2022-04-13T17:12:28.097Z,
    updatedAt: 2022-04-13T17:12:28.097Z,
    __v: 0
  },
 {
    _id: 2,
    type: 'A',
    source: 'B',
    status: 'C',
    totalCount: 7,
    createdAt: 2022-04-13T17:12:28.097Z,
    updatedAt: 2022-04-13T17:12:28.097Z,
    __v: 0
  },
 {
    _id: 3,
    type: 'A',
    source: 'B',
    status: 'C',
    totalCount: 7,
    createdAt: 2022-04-13T17:12:28.097Z,
    updatedAt: 2022-04-13T17:12:28.097Z,
    __v: 0
  }, and so on
```

I want to extract the `totalCount` field and store its value how to do this?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. From which document do you want to extract the `totalCount` value from, considering the result is an array of documents?

Comment: @chridam totalCount is the same for all documents so any will totalCount is ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `totalCount` value will be same in all the objects, you can extract the first value using first index

```
let tc = Allposts[0].totalCount;
```

```js
let data = [{
    _id: 1,
    type: 'A',
    source: 'B',
    status: 'C',
    totalCount: 7,
    createdAt: '2022 - 04 - 13 T17: 12: 28.097 Z',
    updatedAt: '2022 - 04 - 13 T17: 12: 28.097 Z',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    type: 'A',
    source: 'B',
    status: 'C',
    totalCount: 7,
    createdAt: '2022 - 04 - 13 T17: 12: 28.097 Z',
    updatedAt: '2022 - 04 - 13 T17: 12: 28.097 Z',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    type: 'A',
    source: 'B',
    status: 'C',
    totalCount: 7,
    createdAt: '2022 - 04 - 13 T17: 12: 28.097 Z',
    updatedAt: '2022 - 04 - 13 T17: 12: 28.097 Z',
    __v: 0
  }
]

let tc = data[0].totalCount;

console.log(tc);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get only `totalCount` field from query response, you can add .project() in query as below

```
const Allposts = await Post.aggregate().project("totalCount -_id");
```